# Do we need Node.js and Express.js while working with Angular2?

Tags: node.js, express, angular, asp.net-web-api2

I built a sample web application using the following -

- Angular 2
- TypeScript
- ASP.Net WebAPI 2
- Mongo DB
- Karma/Jasmine
- Node.js (only as a server, just to the extent as specified in Angular2 Quick Start)

Considering the above tech stack do we have any need of using Node.js or Express.js for building a production web application? Is any of the above tech is replaceable with Node/Express, for better performance/memory utilization/code maintainability/faster development?

Comment: If you're using an ASP.Net server, you only need Node for the development tools (transpiler, tests, etc)

Comment: If you want SQL database and C# for the back end use ASP.Net WebAPI 2, if you want Mongo DB and JS/TypeScript use Node

Comment: Related: "[Why angular 2 need node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38673650/why-angular-2-need-node-js)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need Node.js for development time tooling - for instance, TypeScript compiler and running Karma/Jasmine tests.

Regarding Express.js - you can do without it. An Angular 2 application does not rely on a back end framework. It could be served as static assets from a web server. Pick any back end framework that suits your needs.